# How to upload images to IPFS with the certain baseURL?

Tags: nft, react, ipfs

I have uploaded one image and set the baseURL for that.
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmQGTQMWRxK33PF4fvnxanyz8aWPPaweYUZeNTVW4gqpQb

Now, I am going to upload more images with the same baseURL, but when I add a new image, it has different image.

How can I implement it?

Comment: "but when I add a new image, it has different image" do you mean different URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload a folder with all the images and json files inside. The folder's URI is going to be your baseURI.
You can also upload images in a different folder from json. But you should know that if you change the content of the folder, the folder URI is going to change too.